# Trouble with method that takes in a function and its arguments

Tags: function, javascript-objects

I am having trouble passing a kata.  I believe I am on the right track, but do not fully understand how to retrieve the desired results.

**The Instructions**

Write a method that takes in a function and the arguments to the function and returns another function which when invoked, returns the result of the original function invoked with the supplied arguments.

**Example Given**

Given a function add

```
function add (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

One could make it lazy as:

```
var lazy_value = make_lazy(add, 2, 3);
```

The expression does not get evaluated at the moment, but only when you invoke lazy_value as:

```
lazy_value() => 5
```

**Here is my half a day endeavor conclusion**

```
var make_lazy = function () {

   var innerFunction = null;
   var array = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     if (typeof arguments[i] == 'function') {
       innerFunction = arguments[i];
     } else {
      array.push(arguments[i]);
     }
    }

    innerFunction.apply(innerFunction, array);

    innerFunction();
};
```

I'm using `arguments` and `apply()` and think I am close?  However I am getting `TypeError: lazy_sum is not a function at Object.exports.runInThisContext` within test results.  Any help, especially understanding what is going on, is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: The last two lines invokes `innerFunction` *twice*.

Comment: In addition to the problem pointed out by Felix Kling what happens if one of the arguments to your innerFunction is also a function? (hint: oops!) I wouldn't normally do this but since you got so close on your own, here's a one-liner you can take apart as a reference: `let makeLazy = (f, ...args) => x => f(...args);`

Comment: You are not returning a function from `make_lazy` Spoiler: `function lazy(fn/*, args*/) {
   return fn.bind.apply(fn, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments, 1)))
}`

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  With your help I added `return function () { innerFunction.apply(innerFunction, array); }` and it worked :).  I understood now that I was not returning the function properly, nor knew that I could do that until now.  **Note:** I also erased `innerFunction();` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...

    return function() {
      return innerFunction.apply(this, array);
    };

};
```

Thanks again all.  Problem solved.